# Spring Webflow's _flowId deprecated

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I've been assigned a situation to migrate a spring-webflow-1.0 project to spring-webflow-2.4.
Also I've been asked to maintain the original _flowId identification i.e. /flows.htm?_flowId=booksearch

In order to do so, I've put together the following flow-definition.xml that is loaded by spring. It uses the WebFlow1FlowUrlHandler I've seen mentioned in a couple of places to allow you to maintain WebFlow1 based url matching but none of the following urls are finding anything

http://localhost:8080/SpringWebFlowExamples/flows.html?_flowId=booksearch
http://localhost:8080/SpringWebFlowExamples/flows.html?_flowId=pensionclaims

The definitions for booksearch-flow.xml and pensionclaims-flow.xml are located in webapps/flows but to no avail?

Would anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Mark.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"/>
</bean>

<flow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry"/>

<flow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices">
    <flow:flow-location-pattern value="/flows/*-flow.xml"/>
</flow:flow-registry>

<flow:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices" view-factory-creator="mvcViewFactoryCreator"
                            development="true"/>

<bean id="internalResourceViewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="mvcViewFactoryCreator" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator">
    <property name="viewResolvers" ref="internalResourceViewResolver"/>
    <property name="useSpringBeanBinding" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean name="/flows.html" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"/>
    <property name="flowUrlHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.webflow.context.servlet.WebFlow1FlowUrlHandler"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```